# Convert Linq query in repository to SelectListItem of ViewModel type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list in my view using EditorFor with a template for the dropdown and UIHint on the viewmodel.

The dropdown is defined in the viewmodel as an IEnumerable.

**ViewModel**

```
public partial class FilmEditViewModel
{
    public int filmID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> filmName { get; set; }
    public string releaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

The repository has a GetSelect method that should return an IEnumerable.

**Repository**

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelect()
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> films = (from f in objContext.tFilm
                            orderby f.filmName
                            select new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = f.filmName,
                                Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?)f.filmID)                        
                            });
        return films;
    }
```

The controller then creates a new ViewModel instance and populates the list from the GetSelect.

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new FilmEditViewModel
        {
            filmName = _repo.GetSelect()
        };
        return View(model);

        //IEnumerable<SelectListItem> films = _repo.GetSelect();
        //var model = new FilmEditViewModel
            //{
            //    filmName = films.Select(f => new SelectListItem
            //    {
            //        Value = f.Value,
            //        Text = f.Text                       
            //    })
            //};
    }
```

The code at the top is what I would expect to work. The commented code below is where I've tried to be more explicit.

Neither works.

They return errors of the form:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'FilmStore.ViewModels.FilmEditViewModel'

How do I convert the query into a SelectListItem that can be passed into the ViewModel?

Other info in case it helps...

**DropDown Template**

```
@model FilmStore.ViewModels.FilmEditViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.filmName, new SelectList(Model.filmName, "Text", "Value"))
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
@using BootstrapSupport
@model Object
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
        <legend>@Model.GetLabel() <small>Details</small></legend>
        @foreach (var property in Model.VisibleProperties())
        {
            using(Html.ControlGroupFor(property.Name)){
                //changed first argument for label to show Validation.cs properties
                @Html.Label(property.GetLabel(), new { @class = "control-label" })
                 <div class="controls">
                     @Html.Editor(property.Name, new { @class = "input-xlarge" })
                     @Html.ValidationMessage(property.Name, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
                 </div>
            }
        }
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn " })
          </div>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[id$='Date']").datepicker(
    {format: "dd/mm/yyyy"        }
    );
    </script>
    }
```

-------Edit for answer--------
The solution below from Mariusz works with a few tweaks to the code elsewhere.

I had to amend the Controller slightly and I cleaned up the code in the Repository. Changes below:

**Repository**

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelect()
{
    return from f in objContext.tFilm
                    orderby f.filmName
                    select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = f.filmName,
                        Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?)f.filmID)
                    };            
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new FilmEditViewModel();
    FilmDropDownViewModel films = new FilmDropDownViewModel
        {
            Items = _repo.GetSelect(),                    
        };

    model.filmName = films;           
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dropdown template is expecting model of type `FilmStore.ViewModels.FilmEditViewModel` but you are passing collection of films. If you want to make editortemplate for it make another view model with Id of chosen value and collection of films.

For example

```
public class DropDownVM
{
  public int PickedId {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items {get;set;}
}

public class FilmEditViewModel
{
  public string releaseDate { get; set; }
  public DropDownVM films {get;set;}
}

//Template view
@model DropDownVM

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PickedId, new SelectList(Model.Items , "Text", "Value"))

//View
@model FilmEditViewModel

//...form etc.
@Html.EditorFor(m =>m.films)
```

Comment: thanks, this works. I've updated the question with a few code changes for mapping the viewmodels to the view.

Answer (score 0):

you're filling the list as you should, but you're missing a placeholder for the *chosen value* from the dropdown list, say for example a ChosenFilmId.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.ChosenFilmId, Model.filmName)
```

In the post action, you'll find the chosen value contained in ChosenFilmId field